# html('blabla') jquery method does not work when production environment

Tags: jquery, symfony

Below is my code which is not complicated at all, my problem is explained into the comments.
This code you're about to read is totally fine in the development environment

```
function click($button) 
{
     // blablabla
     $('#core').fadeOut(300, function () {
            that = this;
            $('.element').fadeIn(300, function () {
                  $(that).empty();
            });
      });
      $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: some_variable,
           success: function (data) {
                // ----------------------------
                // ----------------------------
                // ----------------------------
                // ----------------------------
                // the line below works well in the development
                // environment, which means data is injected into $('#core')
                // ----------------------------
                // In production environment, the line below does not work
                // which means that my jquery object $('#core') is empty as if 
                // $('#core').html(data) is skipped and
                // of course I checked that data is not empty
                // ----------------------------
                $('#core').html(data);
                $('.element').fadeOut(300, function () {
                        $('#core').fadeIn(500);
                 });
            }
       });
}

jQuery(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '#button', function () {
         click(this);
     }
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is `data`? A string? An object? A boolean? `undefined`? What does your console say? What is `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Are you inspecting it with the same browser and same version of the browser both times? What version of jquery is it? What backend are you using? What is the content of some_variable? But I add the question provided by the two questions above, what are you receiving? Make sure you fulfill things that you may think are "useless", they might be crucial, for example the type of the data of which you are receiving.

Comment: Where are you getting Jquery from? Is it in your project or is it downloaded from a repository?

Comment: Yes data is a string and it is a twig template by the way

Comment: Are you *sure* it's a string? What is `console.log(data)`?

Comment: There is no error in my js console, all I can see is that my $('#core') is empty: <div id="core"></div>

Comment: after success: function(data){} put error: function(data) and see if there is an error being caught. Try using firebug in firefox to debug your code.

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes man, console.log(data) gives a very big content as I said

Comment: Just an idea: Do you have more than one element with `id='core'`?

Comment: @Jonast92 jquery version:v1.10.2, I'm using chrome for both, symfony2, some_variable equals my url and it works since my data in the success section is OK

Comment: @jperovic It was the first thing I checked man, "unfortunately" there is only one element with `id="core"`

Comment: Please guys don't forget that that WORKS on the development environment.

Comment: @Jaypal Tried and no error catched

Comment: Found it guys :D, I've removed `$(that).empty();` and it works now on production, can you believe that!!! Merci thanks :D

Comment: Would that show up in you Firebug console? :-/

Comment: Nothing shows up in my code inspector console, I have no sensible explanation x/